# Get total value of one column from a collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an orders table which holds orders.

Each orders can have supplements.

The relation is accessed via

```
$order->supplements;
```

Theres a column on the supplements table called 'unit_price'.

How do I get the total price of all supplemented combined?

Comment: Why you don't use aggreagtes()

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sum You can use `$collection->sum("column")` to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the laravel `sum` query.

```
$total = $order->supplements->sum('unit_price');
```

Should give you the total price

Answer (score 0):

Try using sum aggregates()

```
$totalPrice = $order->sum(function ($query) {
   return $query->supplements->sum('unit_price');
});
```